# z score height of childs using WHO growth standards data

Tags: statistics, standards

I'm using the data of WHO child growth standards to program the calculus of z scores, and I have a problem with the calculation of the length z score, since in the data table lenanthro.txt when it changes from 730 to 731 days of age, just when the length term changes from lenght L to height H, there is a discontinuity in the value of M, which even decreases , that is impossible with the evolution of growth of a child, because having one more day of life would sharply increase the z score. Any ideas on how to deal with this discontinuity?
These are the data of that table (see the rows 730 and 731):

```
sex age l   m   s   loh
1   0   1   49.8842 0.03795 L
1   1   1   50.0601 0.03785 L
......
1   729 1   87.7734 0.03478 L
1   730 1   87.8018 0.03479 L
1   731 1   87.1303 0.03508 H
1   732 1   87.1587 0.03509 H
....
```

Thank's

Comment: Hmm, this is a very interesting question, but the appropriate forum is stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oopss! You're right Robert, I will ask the question in that forum

Comment: I wrote the question in the stats forum, if there is anyone interested, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/522733/z-score-height-of-children-using-who-growth-standards-data